# Inserting T-SQL query text into SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Can anyone help me to get this work.

`[HOD_DESC] LIKE '%r%'` is a formatted T-SQL query and I want insert into a table.

```
EXEC sp_s_saveReportSearch 'x= r ', '[HOD_DESC] LIKE '%r%''
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just escape the quotes by doubling them:

```
EXEC sp_s_saveReportSearch 'x= r ','[HOD_DESC] LIKE ''%r%'''
```

I really hope there's a *good* reason why you're doing this, however.

Answer (score 1):

Double the quotes around quoted part of your SQL string:

```
EXEC sp_s_saveReportSearch 'x= r ','[HOD_DESC] LIKE ''%r%'''
```

In the column, inserted value will be `[HOD_DESC] LIKE '%r%'`